# WinSCP Not Showing .htaccess Files

Tags: ftp

I've recently installed WinSCP, I was using Filezilla but I've read somewhere that Filezilla it's not a good FTP Client, and also read that WinSCP is a better one.

But now that I logged in I realized that there's a problem, I can't see the **.htaccess** files

Comment: There's probably a setting to show/hide dot files.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Do you have `"Show Hidden Files"` option enabled?

By default WinSCP comes with the option `"Show Hidden Files"` set to true.
but sometimes it comes with this option disabled.
To activate this option in order to see hidden files, press: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>

or you can also activate this option by going to:

```
preferences => Panels => Show hidden files
```

In the preferences window, click on `"Panels"` situated on the left menu.

And then on the right side check or uncheck the `"Show Hidden Files"` box to show or hide the files.

[image]

[src](https://www.successfulhosting.com/crm/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=380)

Comment: God.. CTRL+ALT+H is work .... Thanks! My WinScp different is beta (not windows)

Answer (score 5):

After the connection is established, if there are hidden files not being shown, on the **bottom of the remote panel** itself, I noticed there's a small text regarding the number of hidden files. When I clicked this text, those files showed up.

After finding [Cʜᴜɴ's answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/78988/53342), I also tried the shortcut he mentioned:

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>

It actually hides the files if they're being shown. Pressing the shortcut again, they show up again. So it basically toggles the checkbox in preferences.

Comment: Thanks @MartinPrikryl I now understand that the "Panels" screen does exist and is a parent of both remote and local panels. I mistakenly assumed that the screen Cʜᴜɴ mentioned was the remote panel. Just edited my answer.